# Проверка наличия слова "not" в начале строки Python

Tags: python

Дана строка, вернуть новую строку, если "not" нет в начале слова(not + ...). Если же слово "not" уже стоит в начале слова, просто вернуть строку без изменения.

Вот описание, как должно работать(эти же слова используются и в самой программе):
`not_string('candy')` → 'not candy'
`not_string('x')` → 'not x'
`not_string('not bad')` → 'not bad'
`not_string('bad')` → 'not bad'
`not_string('not')` → 'not'
`not_string('is not')` → 'not is not'
`not_string('no')` → 'not no'

При таком коде не проходит только со словом 'no', так как индекс выходит за пределы слова ([2]):

```
    def not_string(str):
          if str[0] == 'n':
            if str[1] == 'o':
              if str[2] == 't':
                return str
          else:
            return "not " + str
```

Comment: `def not_string(s): return s if s.startswith("not ") else "not " + s`

Comment: @MaxU Теперь не проходит с этим вариантом `not_string('not')` → 'not' (выводит 'not not', выполняя else)

Comment: @MaxU всё, разобрался, нужно было убрать пробел `if str.startswith("not")` вместо `if str.startswith("not ")`

Comment: `def not_string(s): return s if s.startswith("not") else "not " + s` - так должно сработать

Comment: `def not_string(s): return s if s[:3]=='not' else f"not {s}"`

Answer (score 0):

```
ss = ['candy', 'x', 'not bad', 'bad', 'not', 'is not', 'no']

def not_string(s):
    return s if s.startswith("not") else "not " + s

for i in ss:
    print(not_string(i))
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]